# How to restore the file type association in iOS

Tags: ios, safari, hyperlink, file-association, wma

Some of you may have tried an App named Phone Drive, it took over the file type like mp3, pdf etc.

But what if I want to restore the association to the default app?

For example, previously when I opened a link to mp3 in Safari, Safari plays it. But when I am using Phone Drive, I need to download it in that App and play it later.

Any suggestion?

Please ignore the below one. iOS doesn't support wma....

---

Some of you may have tried an App named Phone Drive, it took over the file type like wma, pdf etc.

Originally, when I clicked a link to wma file in Safari, it is opened in a player embed in the web page.

However, after I installed and removed that App, when I tap on the same link, Safari pops out an alert says it can not download the link.

Any solution? Thank you.